# Dynamically creating dots/squares inside picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to be able to create X x Y number of boxes / circles / buttons inside a picturebox. EXACTLY like Windows Defrag tool.

I tried to create a layout and keep adding buttons or pictureboxes to it, but its extremely slow and after 200 or so pictureboxes it crashes, runs out of window handles or memory.

What's the alternative? Can you show me a simple piece of code to add boxes just like Defrag tool where I can easily access them like 
`box[x,y].Color = Green` as my app makes progress?

Currently I have this:

```
        private void ResetTableStyles()
        {
            boardPanel.Controls.Clear();
            boardPanel.RowStyles.Clear();
            boardPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();

            boardPanel.RowCount = Rows;
            boardPanel.ColumnCount = Columns;

            for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
            {
                boardPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100f));
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
            {
                boardPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100f));
            }
        }

        private void CreateButtons()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
                {
                    var button = new PictureBox
                    {
                        BackColor = Color.White,
                        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                        Margin = Padding.Empty,
                        Tag = new Point(i, j),
                        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
                    };
                    //button.MouseDown += button_MouseDown;
                    boardPanel.Controls.Add(button, j, i);
                }
            }
        }
```

which as I said doesn't work, after sometime it just crashes and it takes very long time.

Comment: From Microsoft docs : "Typically the PictureBox is used to display graphics from a bitmap, metafile, icon, JPEG, GIF, or PNG file". You are not creating `dots` inside a picturebox, you are creating hundreds of pictureboxes. My advice would be maybe using "System.Drawing.Graphics" class and draw all the boxes and circles  inside the canvas. You can place a panel in your form and call CreateGraphics method of panel to get the Graphics object. The panel can handle mouse and keyboard events. You can know what box/circle is clicked from the event x/y information, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps someone has a better answer, but you could use a `Panel` as the canvas and handle the `Paint` event to draw colored rectangles onto the `Panel`. You could then use the mouse events, such as `MouseMove`, to figure out which cell you're on.

Here is a super-simple proof of concept.

```csharp
// Data.cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
   public class Data
   {
      public int State { get; set; }
      public string Tip { get; set; }
   }
}

// Form1.cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         var rng = new Random();
         _data = new Data[30 * 30];
         for (int i = 0; i < _data.Length; i++)
         {
            _data[i] = new Data
            {
               State = rng.Next(0, 3),
               Tip = $"Data at index: {i}"
            };
         }
      }

      private Data[] _data;

      private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
      {
         using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray))
         using (var buffer = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(e.Graphics,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 450, 450)))
         {
            for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
            {
               for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++)
               {
                  int dataIdx = (y * 30) + x;
                  Data data = _data[dataIdx];
                  if (data.State == 1)
                  {
                     brush.Color = Color.Blue;
                  }
                  else if (data.State == 2)
                  {
                     brush.Color = Color.Red;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     brush.Color = Color.Gray;
                  }
                  buffer.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x * 15, y * 15, 15, 15);
                  buffer.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, y * 15, 450, y * 15); //Gridline
               }
               buffer.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x * 15, 0, x * 15, 450); //Gridline
            }
            buffer.Render(e.Graphics);
         }
      }

      private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
         var point = e.Location;
         int x = point.X / 15;
         int y = point.Y / 15;
         int dataIdx = (y * 30) + x;
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_data[dataIdx].Tip);
      }
   }
}
```

The `Data` class represents the model behind each segment on the panel and is pretty straight forward.

`Form1` has a single control placed on it: a `Panel` named `panel1` with a size of `450 x 450`. Each cell on the panel will be `15 x 15`, so we have 30 columns and 30 rows. In `Form1`'s constructor, we initialize the `Data` that will be used to draw the panel.

Inside of `Form1.panel1_Paint` we iterate through the cells and look up the instance of `Data` for the given cell. Then, based on the `State`, set a color for the cell and draw a rectangle of that color. This is done on a buffer so the panel doesn't flicker when painting.

Inside of `Form1.panel1_MouseMove` we use the location of the mouse pointer relative to `panel1` to figure out which cell the mouse is over, get the instance of `Data` for that cell, and display the `Tip` in the debug window.

You might be able to take this and build upon it, perhaps with a custom `UserControl` so you can easily access each individual cell with the column and row... your `box[x, y].Color = Colors.Green` example above.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, just will change the X, Y, rectangle width, height, all proportional to Panel dimensions and number of elements (boxes) I need. Trying to figure out how to calculate all that properly and dynamically